# What exactly is the contradiction in proving that $h_n(x)$ does not converge uniformly on any bounded interval?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

I am currently going through this pdf https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~b89089/book/Apostol/ch9.pdf and in Exercise 9.2b, page 3, we have the following question.

Prove that $h_n(x)$ does not converges uniformly on any bounded
interval.

\begin{align} h_n(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{x}{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right) & \text{if}\;x=0\;\text{or}\;x\in \Bbb{Q}^c,\\a+\frac{a}{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{bn}\right)& \text{if}\;x\in \Bbb{Q}\end{cases}\end{align}

**PROOF**

\begin{align} \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}h_n(x)=\begin{cases}0 & \text{if}\;x=0\;\text{or}\;x\in \Bbb{Q}^c,\\a& \text{if}\;x\in \Bbb{Q}\end{cases}\end{align}
Suppose for contradiction that $h_n(x)$ converges uniformly on any bounded interval $I$, then $h_n(x)$ converges uniformly on $[c,d]\subset I$. So, given $\epsilon=\max\{|c|,|d|\}>0$, there exists a positive integer $N,$ such that as $n\geq N,$ we have 
\begin{align}\max\{|c|,|d|\}> |h_n(x)-h(x)|=\begin{cases}\left|\frac{x}{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right| & \text{if}\;x=0\;\text{or}\;x\in \Bbb{Q}^c\cap [c,d],\\\left|\frac{a}{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{bn}\right)\right|& \text{if}\;x\in \Bbb{Q}\cap [c,d]\end{cases}\end{align}
which implies that $(x\in \Bbb{Q}^c\cap [c,d])$ or $x=0$

\begin{align}\max\{|c|,|d|\}> \left|\frac{x}{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right| \geq \frac{|x|}{n}\geq \frac{\max\{|c|,|d|\}}{n},\;\forall\;n\geq N,\end{align}
which is absurd. So, $h_n(x)$ does not converges uniformly on any bounded
interval.

**QUESTION**

What is the contradiction in,
\begin{align}\max\{|c|,|d|\}>\frac{\max\{|c|,|d|\}}{n},\;\forall\;n\geq N?\end{align}
Or I'm I missing something? I would be happy if the above can be explained to me. Thanks!

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Please ask only one question per post. Having several questions in the same post is discouraged and such posts may be put on hold, see [meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6464).

Comment: @Shaun: Please, don't close it I'll edit my post!

Comment: Okay, but please fix the title!

Comment: @Shaun: I have edited it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: In the pdf you're linking to, the second-last line of text says "which implies that ($x \in \left[ c, d\right] \cap \mathbb{Q}^c $ or $x = 0$)". The final inequality below this line doesn't hold for $x = 0$ since $\max \lbrace |c|, |d|\rbrace > 0$.

Comment: @Teddan the Terran: I don't still get it. First, why is  \begin{align}\frac{|x|}{n}\geq \frac{\max\{|c|,|d|\}}{n}?\end{align}I think I'll need a detailed and convincing answer!

Comment: @Mike Honestly, that part didn't make a lot of sense to me either.

Comment: @Teddan the Terran: Do you have a better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution in the linked pdf does not make any sense: it does not use at all the values of $h_n$ at rationals, while, in fact, the convergence *is uniform* on bounded subsets of irrationals.

The correct argument comes from the observation that for any every $M>0$, any interval $(c,d)$ (I take $c>0$ for definiteness) contains a rational point $x_M=a/b$ with $a>M$ and $a,b$ relatively prime integers. (Indeed, there are infinitely many rationals in the interval, but if $a\leq M$, then $a/b>c$ implies $b\leq M/c$, and there are only finitely many pairs of positive integers satisfying these bounds.) Therefore,
$$
h_M(x_M)-h(x_M)\geq 1+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{bM}\geq 1,
$$ for any $M$. This is incompatible with the uniform convergence.

Comment: Please, let me read your proof and ask questions before thicking!

Comment: Please, why did you pick an arbitrary $M>0$?

Comment: what exactly bothers you? The negation of the uniform convergence is that for some $\varepsilon>0$, there exist arbitrarily large $M$ and $x\in(c,d)$, possibly depending on $M$, such that $|h_M(x)-h(x)|\geq \varepsilon$. That's what I've shown (with $\varepsilon=1$).

Comment: Thanks  Kostya_I! I understand what you are doing but I fail to get this: Please, what guarantees us the positivity of $b?$ I mean, why did you drop the bar? Also, can you please explain why  $a\leq M$ implies $a/b>c?$

Comment: Any non-empty interval $I$ contains a sub-interval $(c,d)$ with either both $c,d$ positive or both negative. I considered the first case, the second is similar. $a/b>c$ because, well, $a/b\in(c,d)$.

Comment: I get that! So, what guarantees me that $b$ is positive?